# What would happen if no particles were entangled?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Quantum entanglement is important for fields such as quantum computing.  But my question is what would happen to the everyday physical world if all particles suddenly became unentangled?  Nothing?  Complete chaos?  No one knows?

Comment: I don' think that can be answered. You're essentially asking *what would happen if something magic happened*, and the best we can say is that you need to ask a magician not a physicist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *entanglement* is a short hand for *there exists a quantum mechanical wavefunction describing the "entangled* particles".

By

> if all particles suddenly became unentangled

means that quantum mechanics would no longer work as a model of nature.

Without quantum mechanics there would be no nuclei and atoms and chemistry because all these depend on quantum mechanical bound states which make for the stability of everyday matter.

Of course as John says, to go suddenly from a quantum mechanical world to a classical-only world requires a magical incident, and is not predictable, mainly because of the weak interaction and the strong interaction and the energy trapped in the quarks and gluons which only exist within a quantum mechanical framework. As there would be no weak or strong interaction one would guess that  all matter would end up at the stable particles in the [particle table.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg), by the magical process that disappeared quantum mechanics.

Comment: I think a better way of asking this would be, which particles are entangled in the everyday world? Most, none, some?

Comment: @safesphere  it is a different question. My answer is that if gravity is unified in a quantization model, all matter is "entangled", because a quantum mechanical universe equation in theory would exist.  Now the degree of entanglement and whether use can be made of it would be another matter. In the usual jargon entanglement is used for quantum number conservation withing a quantum mechanical system, as spin.